# How do I hash a string in flutter and verify it in php?

Tags: php, flutter, dart, hash

I have a flutter app where I take input from the user and hash it using sha256. I have an api built with php which receives this hashed text. Now I would like to verify if the string matches with other strings in database. I have tried everything I’ve used `password_verify` and `password_equals` and they aren’t working. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: is the string in the DB is a hashed version of the password, or the password as plain text?

Comment: It is a plain text

Comment: Than either don't hash on the client, or hash it on the server, and then use `password equals`

Comment: If you get a standard sha256 hash in the request and have the original in the db, just [hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) the string in the db and do a `==` on the result against the hash you got in the request?

Comment: How do I make a secured request then? I want my server to respond only to the appropriate requests. can you tell me a way I could find if the request data is tampered or is not from the appropriate client?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have tried it. It is not working. Now I'm doubting, Maybe I'm not doing it in the right way. I'll just try it again and let you know.

Comment: _"How do I make a secured request then"_ - Use SSL (https)?

Comment: I don't think ssl will secure the data being transferred because I have seen many websites using ssl and still their data could be seen every time they make a request in the network tab in dev tools in browser.

Comment: _"I don't think ssl will secure the data being transferred"_ - That's **_literally_** what SSL is for; securing the data being transferred. Of course the _clients_ (like browsers, apps etc) can see the information it receives or sends. The network tab is a part of the browser, which is the client.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I got it. ```hash_equals``` is working when I encrypt the data from the database. I was trying it without encrypting it. I'm sorry, My bad and Thank you so much for helping me out.